# Disable NIC interface permanently in RHEL7?

Tags: linux, network-adapter, network-interface

How to disable NIC interface permanently in RHEL7? The command:

```
ifconfig -a
```

should not show an interface after disabling.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo ip link set <NIC_NAME> down
```

this will bring the NIC down , then to remove it from ifconfig listing..

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<NIC_NAME>
```

and comment out all lines there or rename the file, and then restart networking services

```
systemctl restart network
```

hope it helps